# Function that calculates the least amount of notes a ATM will dispense for a given amount

Tags: java, change-making-problem

This is the code currently and it works. Currently have a DB with the type of note and the amount of that note available. This will, later on, remove the amounts of notes from the DB.

I am happy with this solution

I was just hoping there was a more clean way of writing this part of the code to cut down on the lines.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= notes_50 && notes_50 >= 1; i++ ) {
        if(amountRemaining >= 50) {
            amountRemaining = amountRemaining - 50;
            outputNotes_50 ++;
            notes_50 --;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= notes_20 && notes_20 >= 1; i++ ) {
        if(amountRemaining >= 20) {
            amountRemaining = amountRemaining - 20;
            outputNotes_20 ++;
            notes_20 --;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= notes_10 && notes_10 >= 1; i++ ) {
        if(amountRemaining >= 10) {
            amountRemaining = amountRemaining - 10;
            outputNotes_10 ++;
            notes_10 --;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= notes_5 && notes_5 > 1; i++ ) {
        if(amountRemaining >= 5) {
            amountRemaining = amountRemaining - 5;
            outputNotes_5 ++;
            notes_5 --;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can try this for every cycle: ```int deltaNotes = (min((int)amountRemaining/50, notes50-1);
amountRemaining-= 50*deltaNotes;
notes_50 -= deltaNotes;
outputNotes_50+=deltaNotes;```. Not 100% sure, but you can try

Comment: I don't think Brendan's algorithm works correctly once the number of notes is only a few more than what's required.  For example, if I want $200 and the machine contains five $50 notes, I should get four of them, but I'll only get three.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to reduce is not the number of lines of code, but the repetition.

For each denomination we have three related bits of data, the value of the note, how many we have given out, and how many we have left, so we can put them in a data structure:

```java
class NoteInventory {
    // the denomination never changes, so make it final, so we can't accidentally change it
    private final int value;
    private int remaining;
    private int output = 0; // int fields are initialised to zero anyway, but let's make it explicit

    // constructor which takes the denomination and the stock of this note
    public NoteInventory(int value, int remaining) {
        this.value = value;
        this.remaining = remaining;
    }

    // getters, but no setters, we only modify this data by transferring notes
    // from stock to dispensed.
    public int getRemaining() {
        return remaining;
    }

    public int getOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

// we make these modifications together so that the numbers stay consistent
    private void giveNote() {
// if the rest of our code is correct then the exception will never be thrown
// but if our code is wrong we want to find out as soon as possible.
        if (remaining <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Ran out of $" + value + " notes!");
        }
        remaining--;
        output++;
    }
}
    // Arguably this method doesn't belong here,
    // what if we want to change the strategy for dispensing notes? 
    public int dispenseNotes(int amountOutstanding) {
        while (amountOutstanding >= getValue() && getRemaining() > 0) {
            giveNote();
            amountOutstanding -= getValue();
        }
        return amountOutstanding;
    }
```

We use the class like this:

```java
import java.util.List;

public class NoteDispenser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<NoteInventory> inventories = List.of(
                new NoteInventory(50, 3),
                new NoteInventory(20, 5),
                new NoteInventory(10, 6),
                new NoteInventory(3, 0)
        );
        int amountOutstanding = 204;
        for (NoteInventory inventory : inventories) {
            amountOutstanding = inventory.dispenseNotes(amountOutstanding);
        }
        for (NoteInventory inventory : inventories) {
            if (inventory.getOutput() > 0) {
                System.out.println("Gave " + inventory.getOutput() + " $" + inventory.getValue() + " notes");
            }
        }
        if (amountOutstanding > 0) {
            System.out.println("Still owe $" + amountOutstanding);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     for(int i = 0; i <= notes_50 && notes_50 >= 1; i++ ) {
>         if(amountRemaining >= 50) {
>             amountRemaining = amountRemaining - 50;
>             outputNotes_50 ++;
>             notes_50 --;
>         } else {
>             break;
>         }
>     }
> ```

You don't need a loop for this.  You can calculate this directly.

```
outputNotes_50 = amountRemaining / 50;
amountRemaining %= 50;

if (outputNotes_50 > notes_50) {
    outputNotes_50 = notes_50;
}

notes_50 -= outputNotes_50;
```

While this may not seem much shorter, since this only runs once, it will run faster.

Both your original code and this version have a problem though.  If you have only fifties and twenties but want to give out 110, the code will fail.  Because it will count off two fifties and then be unable to give out the final 10.  But 110 could be achieved with one fifty and three twenties.